# add subtitle in navigation bar

Tags: iphone

I want to add subtitle in navigation bar. How can i do this?

Here is image of what i want =>

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6373/80160929.jpg

Let say this is my navigation bar . so how can add sub title which is smaller than title in size?
thanks in advance

Comment: We can add the UILabel in navigation bar. But Apple will approve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own view as the navigationControllers `titleView`.  Here you will need to make a view that contains 2 `UILabels`, size them properly, and set that as the `titleView`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the `prompt` ivar of the `UINavigationItem` object of your `UINavigationBar`.

But afair this is not really a subtitle but a smaller title above the title, so I'm not sure if this helps you in this case.